# How to make 2 Rules work that use the very same Rules Event?

Tags: 7, entities, rules

On a D7 site I have two rules (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) reacting on the same event which is 'After saving a new entityform submission'.

When the actual event occurs only 1 gets fired, even though I've played around with Rule weights. So either I can give precedence to 1 of them or get them to fire at the same time but no luck.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 separate Rules using the same "after update something" event, that's asking for problems.

You should try to rework/redesign those 2 rules somehow. Here are a few ways to do so:

- If both rules don't have any Rules Conditions, then move all the Rules Actions of 1 rule to the other rule (and think of the best "order" to execute all Rules Actions).
- If Rule 1 has a Rules Condition (say) "*Condition1*" and Rules Action (say) *Action1*, and Rule 2 has a Rules Condition (say) "*Condition2*" and Rules Action (say) *Action2*, then use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to merge both rules together (also), with a Rules Action (not Rules condition!) that looks like so:

  > Conditional
  >
  > If Condition 1 then Action 1
  >
  > Conditional
  >
  > If Condition 2 then Action 2

  **Note**: if appropriate, first perform anything related to Rule 2, then Rule 1